# Javascript - Check if last <p></p> is empty

Tags: javascript, html

For a client which uses a WYSIWYG editor for editing their descriptions, I want to check if the last `<p></p>` tag is empty.

Because when they are editing the descriptions, a lot of them we get a empty `<p>` because they leave an blank space or enter in the description on the end. But that empty `<p>` causes some aligning issues for me so I want to check if the last `<p>` is empty so I can hide it, if it is.

This is an example of how it looks most of the time:

```
<div id="description-column">
    <p>Text 1</p>
    <p>Text 2</p>
    <p>Text 3</p>
    <p>Text 4</p>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: `columnElement.lastElementChild.textContent == ""`? - although this doesn't care if the last element is a `p` or not

Comment: Something like `!document.querySelector('#description-column > p:last-of-type').textContent.length` could do the job. Depending on your definition of `empty`.

Answer (score -1):

```
var lastParagraph = document.querySelector('#description-column > p:last-of-type');
if(lastParagraph.textContent === '') {
 lastParagraph.style.display = 'none';
};
```

Comment: Do you just go around various posts copying comments into answers?

Comment: No, I actually didn't see your comment. I can delete my answer if it's a problem.

Comment: No, I dont care about points. Just had the feeling from your three other posts as well. Coincidence happens. Nvm.

Comment: @JavaScript, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). If you have read this post before, you should know that you **shouldn't** comment when what you have to say answers the question (that defeats the whole purpose of an answer. Instead switch that comment out for an answer. You comment for clarification, constructive criticism or minor/transient information.

Comment: @BuddyBob my comment did not answer the question.

Comment: Then why did you say "Do you just go around various posts copying comments into answers??

Comment: @BuddyBob that is obvious enough. Else dont let it bother you and move on.

Answer (score -1):

To first find the correct DOM element, use a query like this:
`document.querySelector('#description-column > p:last-of-type')`
This should return the final `<p>` tag, on which you can then perform a check like this:

```
const element = document.querySelector('#description-column > p:last-of-type');
if (element.innerHTML === '') {
  // Perform task here
}
```

This will check that there are no contents in the element, and allow you to add a class or change the style of it as required.